# Is it possible to issolate Google sign-in into sandboxed iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-signin

I'm evaluating moving 3rd party JavaScripts into sandboxed iFrames in order not allow them access to main page data.

One of the flows we want to move are the Google Sign-In. Right now, we have a javascript and google Button that triggers  the logging flow(open a new window). Thats ok, but we do not want to move the initial js and button into a sandboxed iFrame, then inside this iframe, in some way we will pass the cookie or the token to the main window(postMessage, serverside API or something else).
[Scenario design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNZ5O.png)

Do you think it is a valid scenario?

Regards,